# How to calculate signal after passing through the filter?

Tags: filters, convolution, frequency-response, time-domain

I have the amplitude response of the LPF (here it is generated in `Python`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R = 1e3
C = 400e-9

omega = np.linspace(0,100e3, 100001)
AFR = 2/(4+(R*omega*C)**2)

plt.plot(omega, AFR)
```

[image: Amplitude to frequency response]

and the shape of desired signal I'd like to pass through it:

```
amp = 1

t = np.arange(0,100e-6,2e-9)

def rectangular_pulse(t, amplitude, start, stop):
    wave = np.zeros(len(t))+amplitude
    wave[0:start] = 0
    wave[stop:] = 0
    return wave

plt.plot(t, rectangular_pulse(t, amp, 1, len(t)-2))
```

[image]

I'd like to have a look at the initial signal after passing it through the filter with known amplitude to frequency response characteristics. Am I right, I just need to take convolution of the amplitude response and the pulse or I'm mistaken?

Comment: you're mistaken. You convolve the signal with the *impulse response*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok, I expected so) in this case, can I implement what I want (have a look at the signal after passing through such LPF?)

Comment: yes, it's possible to filter signals.

Comment: for sure)) but how to do it analytically?

Comment: using convolution. I honestly don't understand the question!

Comment: I mean, using the data that I have (I know the amplitude to frequency response characteristic (here I call it LPF) and the input pulse shape and nothing more), how can I calculate/predict the shape of my initial signal (here it is rectangular pulse) after passing the filter (amplitude to frequency characteristic that is known)?

Comment: you need to determine the impulse response. The impulse response is **not** fully defined by the amplitude response (wikipedia is your friend here!)

Comment: for sure, I know what you mean, in case of convolution I should have impulse response ($h(t)$, for example), then I can integrate it with the input signal (it will be convolution); in my case I'm just asking, how can I do what I want (of course, if it is possible in principle)

Comment: I said that three times now. You need to find an impulse response matching your amplitude response. There's infinitely many impulse responses with the same amplitude response, so you can only find one *example* of these.

Comment: ok, so am I right, I can find the impulse response having the data, that I have? If yes, my next question would be, how to do so?

Comment: no, you're not right. again: you can find *one* impulse response, not *the* impulse response. Because there's infinitely many impulse responses to the same amplitude response.

Comment: I don't mind, I just want to get through my purporse) how can I find $one$ impulse response then?

Comment: So, do you know how frequency response and impulse response are related mathematically?

Comment: the first, what goes to my mind is just Fourier transfrom)

Comment: so, do you know, yes or no?

Comment: @MarcusMüller no

Comment: Does your example involve a simple RC low pass filter, with R = 1000 ohms and C = 400 nF? If so, your RC time constant is 400 microseconds. It appears you simply want to input a unit amplitude rectangular pulse with a duration of 100 microseconds. Am I on the right track? If so, it is a common textbook example to convolve the input and impulse response and a simple digital simulation is also very easy.

Comment: @EdV, you're exactlly on the right track) the problem is I don't have impulse response of my filter under design, I just have its amplitude response and the shape of input signal((

Answer (score 3):

> Am I right, I just need to take convolution of the amplitude response and the pulse or I'm mistaken?

Yes, you are mistaken. The amplitude response alone is not sufficient: the transfer function of a first order lowpass filter is complex:

$$H(\omega) = \frac{1}{1+j\omega RC}$$

In order to implement this numerically, you need to sample it at a certain sampling rate. That's a problem, since the transfer function is not band limited and there will be always some amount of aliasing.

You can generate an impulse response or filter multiple different ways but non of them will be "correct" and have some high frequency or causality errors.

1. Sample in the frequency domain and generate an impulse response with an inverse DFT
2. Sample the impulse response directly in the time domain $h(t) = e^{-t/\tau} \cdot u(t)$
3. Calculate the poles and zeros of the transfer function and than create a discrete IIR filter with a bilinear transform.
4. Some sort of least square approximation for either an FIR or IIR filter

The best option depends on the specific requirements of your application and what trade-offs you are willing to make.

Comment: thank you so much for such a detatiled answer! am I right, you postulate, that there is no "correct" way to implement what I want?

Comment: There probably is, but you need to define precisely what exactly "correct" means.

Comment: @Curious If this answer completed your inquiry correctly, please mark it as correct and even upvote it for the responder. Thanks!

Comment: @Hilmar, I'm very inspired with your advices, because I very want to test them; but I have some questions, because some points a bit unclear: 1) in the point 1 how can I sample my amplitude response in frequency domain? can I do it randomly? or how should I connect it with my input test rectangular signal? and didn't get exactly the point 2, could a bit clarify it, thank you!)

Comment: @Hilmar, I tried first two advices from your answer: for inverse DFT I took my amplitude response and tried to apply inverse DFT to it, the result was weird; for sampling in time domain I got exponential falling edge, but rising edge unchanged, which was also strange

Comment: Digital signal processing is fairly math heavy. Without a solid foundation in the proper math, you will not get very far.  I recommend starting with a grad level class or some good test book or online resource. For example: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/

Comment: @Hilmar, ok, thank you for the book!